# failed to generate dynamic type object

Tags: java, database, oop, netbeans-8

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException
Failed to generate dynamic type objectdb.factory.Person
```

Here `Person` is an abstract class and it is extended by another abstract class called `Employee`. The employee abstract class is extended by another class called Janitor.

in the factory class a janitor object is created as:

```
Person janitor1 = new Janitor();
```

Im creating a database but when i run the program i get the error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException
Failed to generate dynamic type objectdb.factory.Person.
```

What can be the reason? tried solving it any different ways but failed.

Comment: http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips-100042/17-enterprise-java-beans/1959-inheritance-and-the-java-persistence-api.html i used this reference to guide me as im new to databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!..i have somehow not addressed the Person abstract class as a Public class. hence why i got the above error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to instatiate an abstract class, but for its own definition an abstract class has no possible direct instantiation. You need to instatiate a concrete class that inherits from it.

Comment: hi thanks for replying so soon. iv made an mistake in writing the code here. im not trying to instantiate an abstract class, the correct code is 
Person janitor = new Janitor()

Answer (score 0):

Since Employee is an abstract class

> new Employee(); won't compile

Comment: hi thanks for replying so soon. iv made an mistake in writing the code here. im not trying to instantiate an abstract class, the correct code is 
Person janitor = new Janitor()